# Hover on dynamic generated span and give the hovered icon active class in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to hover on these Music notes, if i hover on music note 2, then the 1, 2 both should get active classes. And if i hover on 3 then all 3 spans/icons should get active classes.

Like i have done with click event.

So how to do that same thing with hover?

My code looks like this:

```
 <template>
    <div class="track-rating">
       <span :key="note" v-for="note in maxNotes" :class="{ 'active': note <= notes }" @click="rate(note)" class="material-icons mr-1">
        audiotrack
       </span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    export default {
      name: "Rating",
      props: {
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        maxNotes: {
            type: Number,
            default: 3
        },
        hasCounter: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
            notes: this.rating
        };
      },
      methods: {
        rate(note) {
            if (typeof note === 'number' && note <= this.maxNotes && note >= 0)
                this.notes = this.notes === note ? note - 1 : note
        }
      }
   };
 </script>
```

================

```
<template>
   <div>
     <Rating :rating="0"/>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   import Rating from '../Rating';
   export default {
     name: "Test",

     components: {
        Rating
     },
    
   };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, store the currently hovered note and use that to also add the active class.

```
<template>
    <div class="track-rating">
       <span :key="note" 
              v-for="note in maxNotes" 
             :class="{ 'active': note <= notes || note <= hoveredNote }" 
             @mouseover="hoveredNote = note"  
             @mouseleave="hoveredNote = false" 
             @click="rate(note)" class="material-icons mr-1">
        audiotrack
       </span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    export default {
      name: "Rating",
      props: {
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        maxNotes: {
            type: Number,
            default: 3
        },
        hasCounter: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
            notes: this.rating,
            hoveredNote: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        rate(note) {
            if (typeof note === 'number' && note <= this.maxNotes && note >= 0)
                this.notes = this.notes === note ? note - 1 : note
        }
      }
   };
 </script>
```